# CKAN geo_view formats preview

Tags: ckan

I get the following error when I try to add a preview of a `geo_view` formats file.

`geojson_view` works fine.

Here is a cut of CKAN error log file:

```
$ tail ckan_default.error.1.log

[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=14483): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=14483): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=14483): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'.
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] IOError: failed to write data
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] 2015-07-01 11:28:33,473 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /api/i18n/da_DK render time 0.002 seconds
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] **Error - <type 'exceptions.UnboundLocalError'>: local variable 'proxy_service_url' referenced before assignment**
[Wed Jul 01 11:28:33 2015] [error] 2015-07-01 11:28:33,833 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/test-ckan-2-3-datastore/resource/08c27b5c-2130-4a57-997e-8304416de423/new_view render time 0.089 seconds
```

That might look like a failed write is the problem, but where is this?

I used CKAN 2.3 package installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is pull request to fix this problem: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-geoview/pull/19

You can either wait until this this gets merged or use directly the code provided.